# Does the uncomputability of Kolmogorov complexity follows from Rice Theorem?

Tags: logic, computability, kolmogorov-complexity

I was reading the proof of uncomputability of Kolmogorov complexity by Li and Vitányi book and thinking if there isn't another way to do this simpler using Rice theorem. I came up with this argument. Can you say to me if it is correct?

**Definition**: The set $A ⊆ N$ is an index set if it has the property that if $x ∈ A$ and $\phi_x = \phi_y$ , then $y ∈ A$.

Rice theorem states:

**Theorem**: Suppose that $A$ is an index set not equal to $∅$ or $\mathbb{N}$. Then A is not computable.

The conditional absolute complexity can be defined as (by Li and Vitányi book's definition):

$$C(x|y) = \min \{ |p| : \phi(\langle y,p \rangle) = x \}$$

We have: $\phi(\langle y,p \rangle) = \phi_y(p)$ by the enumeration theorem and property of the universal additively optimal $\phi$:

$$C(x|y) = \min \{ |p| : \phi_y(p) = x \}$$

But $A = \{ p : \phi_y(p) = x \}$ is a index set. Because if any  $p \in A$ and  $\phi_p= \phi_q$, then (this is the step I have doubts) $\phi_y(p) = \phi_y(q)$, because  $\phi_y$  can be interpreted as a program that receives other programs $p$ and $q$, and if the programs are equal so is $\phi_y(p)$ and $\phi_y(q)$. Then $q \in A$.

So $A$ is a index set and also is not $\emptyset$ or $\mathbb{N}$ (because  there is a  program $p$ such that $\phi_y(p) \not = x$). So, by Rice Theorem, $A$ is not computable, and $C(x|y)$ also. And so $C(x) = C(x|\varepsilon)$ is also uncomputable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument that $A$ is an index set is not correct: you haven't used anything particular about $y$, so your argument would imply that $$\{p: \phi_y(p)=x\}$$ would be an index set for **every** choice of $y$. But that's clearly incorrect: for example, take $x=1$ and let $\phi_y(p)=1$ if $p=0$ and $0$ otherwise. By the padding lemma, this is not an index set.

While we may *want to think* of $\phi_y$ as acting on computable functions in a well-defined way rather than natural numbers, that doesn't mean that it actually *does*.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, yes it is true. And if we specify $y=0$ and take the set $A= \{ p : \phi_0(p) = x \}$, where $\phi_0 = \phi$ is the universal additively optimal p.c. function. Do you think it can work? $A$ would be a index-set making the above argument I did?  If it is we could show directly $C$ is not computable. But, in general, do you think this line of thought with Rice Theorem is promising?

Comment: I mean, take $A = \{  p : \phi_0(p) = x\}$, with $\phi_0$ the universal p.c. ad. ot. fucntion.  Suppose $p \in A$ and $\phi_p = \phi_q$. Then $\phi_0(p,z) = \phi_0(q, z)$, for all $z$, by the enumeration theorem. In special for z the null string (or 0), we would have $x= \phi_0(p) = \phi_0(q)$.  And $q \in A$. Then $A$ is a index set, not computable by Rice. And we have also that $C(x) = \min \{ |p| : \phi_0(p) = x\}$ would be uncomputable.